# r3f gltf model recieveShadow create line patterns

Tags: gltf, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have created simple react-three-fiber scene with default renderer and watch gltf model and once i have make it recieveShadow it starts creating line patterns under pointLight

Have you ever encountered similar problem?
Is there any workaround?

[gltf model with unwanted line patterns created after recieveShadows=true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LCab.png)

I tried to cast and recieve shadows in recursive function as my watch model is multidimensional.
Shadows casting works perfectly as expected but receiving create mentioned line patterns on model

[recursive function for receiving and casting shadows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fylw.png)

Thanks in advance for tricks and tips

Answer (score 0):

this where 'bias' parameter should be tweaked:

```
const SHADOW_MAP_SIZE = 2048;
const SHADOW_MAP_BIAS = -0.000001;

<spotLight
    shadow-mapSize-height={SHADOW_MAP_SIZE}
    shadow-mapSize-width={SHADOW_MAP_SIZE}
    shadow-bias={SHADOW_MAP_BIAS}
    castShadow
/>
```

not sure why it's negative, however it seems it should go negative
`shadow.bias = -0.005`, reference https://discourse.threejs.org/t/hello-i-am-facing-the-problem-with-shadow-stripes-on-model/18065/9